# Can an Unseen Servant trigger an Alarm spell, and can said Alarm be customized?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

As an [Unseen Servant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/unseen-servant) is "shapeless", its size is not defined.
The [*Alarm*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/alarm) spell, however, relies on a creature's size (Tiny or larger) to be activated.
Therefore, I'm not sure if an Unseen Servant, when commanded to walk through a location containing an *Alarm*, would trigger said *Alarm* or not. I would think it does, but I might be wrong (maybe the Unseen Servant's size value is "null"), hence the question.

Also, one of the two ways to receive an *Alarm* notification is mental. I'm wondering whether that notification can be customized, so that if the Unseen Servant crosses through *Alarm* #1, you can get a different "ping" than for *Alarm* #2. Again, I would think so, but it's better to verify (maybe it's always the same sound regardless).

Finally, I'm almost certain that if you go back and forth through an *Alarm* zone, you will repetitively get the "ping", but I just want to be 100% sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61620/discussion-between-nautarch-and-gael-l).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### No, it still isn't a creature.

Unfortunately, the requirements for Alarm are clear in the spell description (as you stated) with the trigger requiring a Tiny or Larger creature. Because unseen servant is not a creature, it does not satisfy the requirements to trigger the Alarm (just like an illusion wouldn't trigger the alarm, either.)

As for customization of Alarm - that is up to discussing that with your DM and covers both the alert and the inclusion of *Unseen Servant* as a potential trigger.

Comment: A thief can use unseen servant to walk into your camp and take anything not secured...

Comment: This is now out of date due to an errata

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Is it though? Having a size does not a creature make, methinks.

Comment: @thomas it can be outdated, even if the answer is the same.

Answer (score 16):

## No.

*Alarm* (PHB p.211, emphasis mine):

> Until the spell ends, an alarm alerts you whenever a Tiny or larger **creature** touches
> or enters the warded area.

*Unseen Servant*  (PHB p.284, emphasis mine):

> This spell creates an invisible, mindless, shapeless, Medium **force** that performs simple tasks at your command until the spell ends.

*Alarm* reacts to creatures; *Unseen servant* doesn't create a creature, so it can't trigger Alarm. Note that this has nothing to do with size.

Comment: Oh. Dammit. Right. Creature. Forgot about that. But...... If an Unseen Servant is holding an insect, then maybe...

Comment: @Mindwin Including unconscious ones ?

Comment: @Mindwin I seem to be getting on your nerves, which is not my intention. In hindsight, the real question I should have asked is "how can you know when an Unseen Servant finishes a task if you don't see/hear him?" Then people would have suggested probably better solutions than the one I'm attempting to validate above. I am deeply sorry for all the time you lost in dealing with me. But I wish you a good day.

Comment: @GaelL Probably not. Had you got on my nerves, I'd have walked away. I checked your profile, you are new to the stack as a whole, so I'd want to give you some pointers: the stack is bad for back-and-forth conversations like what you are trying to have. This is not a forum. You formulate a question, then get answers. Read more from one of our moderators https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7271/11402

Comment: This answer is now out of date, due to an errata

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I’ve updated the quoted spell text to match the errata’d version.